# You got me mad now => what's the role of "now" here?

Tags: grammar, meaning

Just what kind of secret grammar rule does "now" have to make "You got me mad" ungrammatical when "You got me mad now" is grammatical?

---

PS: I saw many other people online said like "No one says like you got me mad", while I saw a lot of pictures or meme images that have captions on them such as "You've got me mad" or "You got me mad now" etc.

Comment: What makes you think "You got me mad" is ungrammatical?

Comment: Do not try to learn grammar from memes. That is slang, and it's not always going to be grammatically correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote a bunch and then realized I misinterpreted the question.  I'll leave the bunch because I think it is still useful.

I believe "You got me mad" uses "got" as a simple past tense of "get". So "now" doesn't make sense with it because "got" is in the past.

"You have got me mad now" is better because "have got" suggests that something in the past created a condition that exists now.

"You got me mad now", while incorrect, might be used in a meme or poster for the reason described below.

--

Most people would say, "You made me mad." Using "got" instead of "made" is sometimes used to suggest that the person speaking is uneducated or simple-minded. When trying to emphasize that you are stubborn or uncompromising, it can help to suggest that you don't think too much.

"Now" is used in the sentence to suggest that the the listener has done something, really bad. The listener may have done many bad things, but the speaker was willing to overlook them because the speaker is slow to anger.  But *now* the listener has done something so bad that the speaker is finally angry.

"I didn't mind you flirting with my girlfriend. I ignored you borrowing my book and not returning it.  I looked the other way when you put your feet on my table.  But then you put pineapple on my pizza. You've got me mad now!"

Answer (score 3):

"You got me mad" and "You got me mad now" are slang.

To "get mad" means to "become angry", but in slang, you can "you get me mad" to mean "you cause me to become angry". That is one of the slang meanings of "get".

The word "now" just means "at this time" - the usual meaning. The past tense is a slang shortening of the present perfect that can be applied to "have got", but only in slang.

So both are grammatically incorrect but may appear as slang.  Analysis of slang grammar is very advanced since there are so many slangs. It is an interesting exercise for theoretical linguists, but not of much use for learners of English.